# SQL: Select latest price of each product?

Tags: sql

Im having a hard time with a homework... I need to select last unity price by date!

This is the way im doing it:

```
SELECT CodProduct,UnitPrice,MAX(DateDeliver)
FROM Exemplo.dbo.sells
WHERE CodProduct is NOT NULL
GROUP BY CodProduct,UnitPrice
```

What im doing at the moment gives repetead codproduct

Comment: im using group by what you suggest?

Comment: Pls. add your DB name like SQL SERVER,ORACLE,MYSQL etc

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to find the latest date for each product, and then you need to match that date and product to the main table to find the unit price that goes with the product and date:

```
SELECT s.CodProduct, s.UnitPrice, s.Date
FROM Exemplo.dbo.sells s INNER JOIN
      (SELECT s2.CodProduct, MAX(s2.Date) As MaxDate
       FROM Exemplo.dbo.sells s2 GROUP BY s2.CodProduct) md ON
             s.CodProduct = md.CodProduct AND 
             s.Date = md.MaxDate
```

That should give a list of the Products and their most recent unit prices.

Comment: If they have 100 products and they want the last price for each, this is wrong.

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'CodProduct'.

Comment: I edited the answer to avoid that ambiguous column name error.  The tables are always explicitly specified for each column now.

Comment: I still get repeated codproduct... I think this should be easy but having hard time

Comment: Make sure you refresh the page.  It wasn't showing my changes until I did that.  The first line should say "SELECT s.CodProduct, s.UnitPrice, s.Date".

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need something like this (not exactly your table definition):

```
select p1.ProductId, p1.Price
from
(
  select p.ProductId, max(p.Date) [date]
  from Product p
  group by p.ProductId
)x
join Product p1 on x.ProductId = p.ProductId and x.[date] = p1.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE to "rank" all the products so that the most recent date a product has a unit price with have a row number of 1. Then in your main `SELECT` you just filter `WHERE rn = 1`. The code would look something like this:

```
;WITH OrderedDates AS
(
    SELECT 
        CodProduct
        ,UnitPrice
        ,DateDeliver
        ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CodProduct ORDER BY DateDeliver DESC
    FROM Exemplo.dbo.sells
    WHERE CodProduct is NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
    CodProduct
    ,UnitPrice
    ,DateDeliver 
FROM OrderedDates
WHERE rn = 1
```